# Diferença entre back-end e front-end?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, front-end, back-end

Galera, há uma página home que possui 3 filtros:

- (select) Tipo do imóvel: Casa ou Apartamento
- (select) Tipo de negócio: Compra ou Aluguel
- (input) Cidade ou bairro

A pessoa entra com os 3 parâmetros de busca e clica no botão "buscar". Em seguida é mostrado os imóveis para comprar ou alugar de acordo com a cidade/bairro que ela informou.

Minha duvida é: A filtragem dos imóveis mediante aos parâmetros que foram informados na home e que serão mostrados na tela seguinte, é serviço de front-end ou back-end?

Valeu

Comment: Depende bastante, de onde vai vir esses dados, se for de uma banco de dados seria back-end mesmo, se for de uma lista feita no HTML, seria front, cada caso é um caso, esclareça um pouco mais sua dúvida.

Answer (score 7):

Provavelmente é uma ação executada no `back-end`, pois a filtragem geralmente é feita via `SQL Query`, então para realizar operações no banco de dados é necessário uma linguagem de `back-end` como o `PHP`.

Porém isso pode variar de acordo com o desenvolvedor, pode acontecer um outro caso, como: ter um `javascript` que após as seleções envia um `Ajax` para o `PHP` que então realiza a busca, nesse caso a filtragem é feita no `front-end` mas a busca é executada pelo `back-end`.

Pode-se saber mais nesses links:

[Wikipédia - Back e Front end](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_e_back-end)

[Fábio Lobo - Diferença entre back e front end](http://fabiolobo.com.br/o-que-e-front-end-e-back-end.html)

[Tabless - Iniciantes - Client e Server side](http://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/obasico/o-que-front-back.html)

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** - Depende.

**Versão longa**: Você deve levar em consideração o tráfego de dados e experiência do usuário.

Se seu volume de dados for pequeno (algumas centenas de registros), simplesmente transfira a coleção completa para o *client* e filtre localmente. A execução de filtragem no back-end, neste caso, é contraproducente, já que você está executando no servidor operações que o *client* pode executar sem muito esforço.

Se sua coleção for extensa você pode realizar os processos de filtragem, ordenação e paginação no servidor e enviar apenas o conteúdo a ser vizualizado no momento.

Answer (score 4):

**Front-End**

O front-end seria a parte visual do site ou sistema.

Quando falamos "Vou desenvolver o front-end do site" quer dizer a mesma coisa que "Vou desenvolver o HTML, CSS e/ou JS do site". Front-end é tudo que fica na frente (front)

**Back-End**

É a parte de traz do site, aonde a mágica toda acontece, aonde o usuário não vê funcionando como as requisições SQL, envio de emails, etc. O Back-end (atrás) seria a programação, por exemplo, o PHP.

No seu caso, os `selects` e o `input` fazem parte do **front-end** mas o resultado que se da depois que clicar no botão, o responsável é o **back-end** (a programação), que trouxe do SQL as informações necessárias.

Resumindo a sua questão:

**A filtragem dos imóveis mediante aos parâmetros que foram informados na home e que serão mostrados na tela seguinte, é serviço de front-end ou back-end?**

*Resposta: É serviço do back-end*

Answer (score -1):

Tudo que você precisa de um processamento por trás é back-end. Nesse caso você vai ter que manipular receber, manipular e devolver dados.

Pense em front end simplesmente como algo vai ser exibido, a estilização.

No entanto você pode fazer usando uma linguagem back-end tipo Java ou com Javascript que é usado tanto pra back quanto front-end.

Answer (score -1):

Front-End é a parte da frente, visual.

No Front-End você preenche os formulários com os dados a serem enviados ao Back-End.

Back-End é a parte de trás, onde ficam os dados. O Front-End envia os dados para o Back-End que pesquisa os dados no banco de dados (ou outro local de armazenamento de dados) conforme os parâmetros passados pelo Front-End e devolve para o Front-End.

É possível também que o Back-End envie todos os dados para o Front-End que vai filtrar conforme os parâmetros desejados, mas tal procedimento não é recomendado para grandes quantidades de dados.